# Changing the Application icon in Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I have created an Application in Facebook for my Android app. At the time of setting up,I missed to add my app icon there.
How to edit the icon ?
Somebody please help.

I need to change this custom icon to my app icon.
[image]

Comment: You can change the app icon in App details

Comment: yes.i figured it out :) thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i figured out this.It can be changed from App Details tab.